# Escape zero character in number format

Tags: c#, string-formatting

is there a way to escape zero -character as character in C#, when using integer's .ToString() -method?

Example code:

`(112233).ToString("ZeroHereAsChar:_0_NumberHere:0")`

As a result I would like to get this string:

`ZeroHereAsChar:_0_NumberHere:112233`,

but now i'm getting:

`ZeroHereAsChar:11223_NumberHere:3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [backslash as an escape character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0c899ak8(v=vs.100).aspx#SpecifierEscape):

```
(112233).ToString("ZeroHereAsChar:_\\0_NumberHere:0");
```

or with a verbatim string literal:

```
(112233).ToString(@"ZeroHereAsChar:_\0_NumberHere:0");
```

Comment: Yeah! Works, you are a GURU!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
string.Format("ZeroHereAsChar:_0_NumberHere:{0}", 112233);
```

GOOD Luck!!!